# Compute new column based on keyword and split

Tags: python, string, pandas, series

I have a dataframe like this:

```
>>> df1
                         overall
0  class1-10/class2-11/class3-13
1  class3-31/class2-22/class1-23
2                abc/def/xyz/prq
```

I want to compute 3 columns class1 , class2 & class3 if they are found in 'overall' . 
desired o/p

```
          overall                 class1  class2  class3
0  class1-10/class2-11/class3-13    10    11      13
1  class3-31/class2-22/class1-23    23    22      32
2                abc/def/xyz/prq     NaN  NaN     NaN
```

How this can be done in pythonaic way?
Thanks

Comment: With regex groups as documented [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)?

Comment: I am trying to use str.extract here .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way without regex is to use `try` / `except`:

```
def splitter(x):
    try:
        return [int(i.split('-')[1]) for i in sorted(x.split('/'))]
    except IndexError:
        return [np.nan] * 3

df[['class1', 'class2', 'class3']] = df['overall'].apply(splitter).apply(pd.Series)

print(df)

                         overall  class1  class2  class3
0  class1-10/class2-11/class3-13    10.0    11.0    13.0
1  class3-31/class2-22/class1-23    23.0    22.0    31.0
2                abc/def/xyz/prq     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

It may be tempting to use `str.extract` but it only matches the first match as per the docs. On the other hand, `str.extractall` outputs a bit too complex dataframe to work with. We will resort to `df.apply`.

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'(class\d+)-(\d+)')

def func(x):
    data = regex.findall(x[0])
    for class_name, value in data:
        df.loc[x.name, class_name] = value

df.apply(func, axis=1)
print(df)

#                           overall class1 class2 class3
#  0  class1-10/class2-11/class3-13     10     11     13
#  1  class3-31/class2-22/class1-23     23     22     31
#  2                abc/def/xyz/prq    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: will this not be easy with .str.extract ?

Comment: @BharatSharma No. like I mentioned `str.extract` stops on the first match

Answer (score 1):

Use -

```
def split_cols(x):
    for item in x['overall'].split('/'):
        if item.startswith('class'):
            pairs = item.split('-')
            x[pairs[0]] = pairs[1]
    return x
df.apply(split_cols, axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
    class1  class2  class3  overall
0   10  11  13  class1-10/class2-11/class3-13
1   23  22  31  class3-31/class2-22/class1-23
2   NaN NaN NaN abc/def/xyz/prq
```

**Explanation**

The `split_cols()` function takes care of creating the extra columns.

It splits by `/` first, checks for presence of `class` in the splits

It then splits again with `-`, makes a column with the first split and the value for that column as the second split.

The whole thing then is put through the `apply` function